# How to create a new list for each line in a file?

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to create a soduko styled program.
A notepad/word document is uploaded into Python and I want Python to check:

Each line (row) has the same number of characters
Each column has the same number of characters
No characters are repeated twice in either a column or in a row
Every character is used once and only once per column and per row

The file uploaded can either be a numerical soduko or an alphabetical soduko.

So far, I have managed to load, open and read the document and append each line of the document as a list. Below I will show my coding for appending to a list:

```
my_list = [line.strip() for line in open(filename)]

print (my_list)
```

But this puts all my lines inside a bigger list.
For example, if my document read:

```
1 2 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
```

It would read my_list as follows: `[['1 2 3'], ['2 3 1'], ['3 1 2']]`

I'm relatively new to Python and have no idea how to count individual items from a list within a list so this is quite complicated for me.

Any suggestions or tips on how to progress/alter my coding to make this easier for me?

Answer (score 1):

You could `split` each line with its own comprehension:

```
my_list = [[x for x in line.strip().split(' ')] for line in open(filename)]
```

Note that this oneliner, much like your original code, won't close the file handle it opened. A much safer approach would be to open it separately:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    my_list = [[x for x in line.strip().split(' ')] for line in f]
```

Comment: @Goodies except the OP has already read in the data, so I suspect the question title is incorrect.

Comment: @Goodies in the same fashion the OP's current code won't. Ultimately, the question in hand was about splitting the rows read from the file (at least the way I understood it)

Comment: Thanks - this has worked to put the commas in the list...It's still all in one big list but this is not a problem... as long as I can somehow manipulate this!! How can I now manipulate these lists with inside a list?

Comment: @LewisFirmin I don't understand what exactly you're asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The coding provided above has worked - now I still have 3 lists within one bigger list. The only difference is now within each 'mini list', the characters are separated by commas which allows me to manipulate the list more easily I believe. The big list now reads my_list = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '1'], ['3', '4', '5', '1', '2'], ['4', '5', '1', '2', '3'], ['5', '1', '2', '3', '4']]

I am not sure how to access each mini list, e.g to check how many times each character is used etc. I know how to do this for lists in general... but not for lists within lists?

Comment: You can access a list's member with the `[]` operator. If that's a list, you can apply the operator to it again. So to access the first element of the second list, you could use `my_list[1][0]` (note that indexes are zero-based)

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of most of it. I'm not quite clear on your final spec, but you can probably figure it out from here.

```
from sets import Set

with open(filename) as f:
    my_list = [[x for x in line.strip().split(' ')] for line in f]

    #Each row has same number of characters
    #Each column has the same number of characters
    counts = [len(x) for x in my_list]
    if len(Set(counts)) > 1:
        print "SAME NUM ERROR"

    #No characters are repeated twice in a row
    row_len = len(my_list[0])
    for row in my_list:
        if len(Set(row)) < row_len:
            print "ROW REPEAT ERROR"

    #No characters are repeated twice in a column
    col_len = len(my_list)
    for i in range(col_len):
        col = [row[i] for row in my_list]
        if len(Set(col)) < col_len:
            print "COL REPEAT ERROR"
```